# Angular: synchronize all FormControls with model changes

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I have a set of **FormControls** (created via FormBuilder):

```
this.someForm = this.fb.group({
     name: '',
     size: '',
     price: '',
   });
```

is there any other way to update them from the model ( in our example `someProduct`):

```
let someProduct = {
  name: 'shirt',
  size: 'XL',
  price: '20',
}

private updateForm(product) {
  this.someForm.controls.name.setValue(this.someProduct.name);
  this.someForm.controls.size.setValue(this.someProduct.size);
  this.someForm.controls.price.setValue(this.someProduct.price);
};

updateForm(someProduct);
```

Especially taking in account that it could be a lot of `FormControls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this could be the following

```
this.someForm.patchValue(this.someProduct);
```

**[Live Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/5ir4q8q10QkNlhHh0zuy?p=preview)**